# webview.loadUrl works fine when I debug the app. But when I generate a signed APK, it doesn't work.

Tags: android, webview

When I call webview.loadUrl in debug environment, it works fine. But when I call webview.loadUrl in signed APK, it doesn't get called. What might be the reason?

Below is my code snippet:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
```

Comment: can u check in your build.gradle minifyEnabled false, is it true?

Comment: @shishram Its true

Comment: make it false or you have to write rules for your proguard to allow webview

Comment: Its working if I remove minify enabled. But the app size is increasing. So I tried adding this rule to proguard -keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
} and made minifyEnabled true. But it doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: you can check my answer below @Anirudh

Comment: yes that should work, remember if u enable it to true it might break lot of functionalities so you have to be sure about every aspects if you're keeping it to true!

Answer (score 3):

Here are two approach you can apply:

Approach 1:- you can apply this rule for your `app` `proguard-rules.pro` to javascript work.

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

try uncommenting this as well from `proguard-rules.pro`

```
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Approach 2:- You can make your `build.gradle` `minifyEnabled false`

I hope it helps!

Comment: Its working if I remove minify enabled. But the app size is increasing. So I tried adding this rule to proguard -keepclassmembers class * { @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>; } and made minifyEnabled true. But it doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: check edit and try. but make sure proguard doesn't break other functionalities/libraries or other code.